# How do I prove that $n^n > (n+1)^{n-1}$?

Tags: calculus, inequality, proof-writing, exponentiation

It seems simple enough, and by using brute force it's easy to see that $n^n$ will always be slightly larger for any $n \ge 3$. I tried comparing ratios and also using induction, but nothing is conclusive. I would imagine that the epsilon proof would be the correct way to do this but I'm not very familiar with it and I would rather avoid such arduous proofs when I have to solve similar problems in a limited time frame.

Comment: Your inequality is wrong for $n=1$ and obvious for $n\geq2$.

Comment: Hint: consider the function $x^{1/(x-1)}$...

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Could you elaborate on how it is obvious for $n\geq 3$?

Comment: Presumably an obvious typo in the title.

Comment: @Wojowu Use $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n<e$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg OP might not know about $e$.

Comment: @Wojowu I do, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: it is equivalent to $$n+1>\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

Comment: Thanks man! I feel really silly after retrying it and getting this as well...